# differences between in, on, at, for, during when describing a period of time

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I don't know which is the most proper preposition in the sentences below.

1. They eat a special dish ***during*** the first three days of the New Year.
2. They eat a special dish ***in*** the first three days of the New Year.
3. They eat a special dish ***for*** the first three days of the New Year.
4. They eat a special dish ***at*** the first three days of the New Year.
5. They eat a special dish ***on*** the first three days of the New Year.

I would like to mean that they cook a large quantity of dish before New Year, and eat it 9 times - 3 times of meals x 3days.

And can I construct the sentence like these:

- The dish is good for (helps) them **during** the busy first three days of the New Year because they don't need to cook if they have the dish.
- The dish is good for (helps) them **in** the busy first three days of the New Year because they don't need to cook if they have the dish.
- The same sentence with "**at**"
- The same sentence with "**on**"

Comment: Don't overthink this one. Preposition use in English is *very* flexible - ***over*** and ***through[out]***, for example, are alternatives that you could have included here. Plus you could have a "zero preposition" (nothing at all) in that position within the utterance. Note that ***at*** doesn't work at all in your context (it refers to a *point* in time, not a *range*), but all the others are at least "credible", and would normally all be understood to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At" means a "Point in Time" ; not suitable to mean a "Period of Time".

> "I went out at midnight"

"In" means ""At some time in a Duration" ; suitable to mean a "Period of Time".

> "I will come back in July"

"On" means "At some time in a Duration" ; hence suitable.

> "I came on Sunday"

"For" means "Extending, lasting" ; hence not suitable.

> "We watch TV for hours"
> "We ate for 3 Hours"
>
> Using "for" in your case might mean that the ritual eating went on continuously for 3 Days !

"During" means "At some time in a Duration" ; hence suitable.

> "During winter, it snows heavily"

You could also add the the word "Only" to mean that they eat nothing else.

> During [ or In or On ] the first three days of the New Year, three times a Day, they eat only this special dish, which is cooked in large quantities to help avoid repeated cooking.

"During" is the best sounding here!

Comment: I consider that **for** would be acceptable if the dish is eaten at every meal during those three days.

Comment: I agree , that was why I avoided "wrong" & used "not suitable" ; It might be **ambiguous** ; Eg "We fasted for 3 Days" or "We ate for 3 Days" ; @KateBunting